# Trigger.io iOS Plugin returning data from call back

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I am creating a trigger.io plugin for a alert prompt.
Trying to return data from a the alert prompt.
This is my code:

```
 // Prompt
+ (void)show_prompt:(ForgeTask*)task{
    // Create the alert 
    UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                     message:@"Message"
                                                    delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];    
    UITextField *promptTextBox = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];

    [promptTextBox setTag:30050]; // set tag to find the text box
    [promptTextBox setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [prompt addSubview:promptTextBox]; // add it to the alert
    [prompt show]; //show alert

    }

 // Call back
+ (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex task:(ForgeTask*)task
{
        // Grab the reply from text box
        UITextField* promptTextBox = (UITextField*)[alertView viewWithTag:30050];
        NSLog(@"%@", [promptTextBox text]); // output to log   
        [task success:nil]; // output call back

}
```

The above does not work as I when i try to do **[task success:nil];** and including **task:(ForgeTask*)task** the call back stops working.

But with out **[task success:nil];** & **task:(ForgeTask*)task** the NSLog does work.

How would I get around this?

Comment: How do you call this from javascript

Comment: @V-Xtreme Trigger.io have created there own notification plugin see - https://trigger.io/modules/notification/current/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to return `[promptTextBox text]` to the calling JavaScript?

How about this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [promptTextBox text]); // output to log   
[task success:[promptTextBox text]]; // output call back
```

... or am I missing the point?

Comment: How do you call this from javascript